# C FILE I/O, USING TXT FILE

Tags: c

I am just learning C language and I am experiencing a problem with implementing a program 
with test.txt file as input to the program.

contents of `test.txt` file is:

> 1 30 30 40 50 60
>  2 40 30 50 60 60
>  3 30 20 10 20 30
>  4 40 20
>   10 10 30
>  5 20 10 10 10 30

and I am trying to get average score of each student 1~5.

so I implemented as below:

```
while(cnt)      //I set cnt 5 to repeat it for 5 times                     
{         

    fseek(fp, 2, SEEK_CUR);        //to ignore index number in first + blank
    acc=0;                         //clear data in acc
    while(1)
    {
        score=fgetc(fp);

        if(score==' ')         
            fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);   // if it is black then ignore and move
        else if(score=='\n')          // if I meet enter then break
            break;
        else
        {
            acc+=score;              //get total score of a student
        }
    }
    cnt--;

    printf("%d ", acc/5);           //get average score and print
}
```

But result of program is

> 58 
>   58 
>   58 
>   58

I can't figure out what's wrong...

they must be 5 output of program because there is 5 student in there

but it gave only 4 student's average score and all output are same..

Comment: There's no need to yell the title IN ALL CAPS, since it's already big and bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a are a few problems with your code. Among them:

- You are using `fgetc` which reads characters, one character at a
  time. This will not work for a score of "50" if you want to read one
  score at a time.
- You are directly using the result of "fgetc" as a number. This is
  wrong: `fgetc` will return character codes, not numbers. So if you
  have ASCII, when `fgetc` reads 1 it will return 49.

I suggest you try using `fscanf("%d", ..)` instead.

Comment: I have a question.. fscanf ignore Blank?? and get only meaningful datum??

Comment: @Eureuerung `fscanf` ignores blanks **for certain format specifiers**. It so happens that it does ignore blanks for `%d` so you are in luck: if you call `fscanf("%d", &x);` 5 times you will get 5 expected values.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc` you fetch ascii value of character by character, which will not work.

You can refer the below code.

```
int arr[6];
while(cnt--) {         
    for(acc = 0, i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i]); 
        if (i > 0)
            acc += arr[i];              //get total score of a student
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[0], acc/5);           //get average score and print
}
```

Comment: You could have used a loop to fill `arr`.Also,`&arr[0]` in `printf` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see that someone actually learn from mistakes (previous question)

First of all if you know number of studends up front you probably should use `for` loop instead of `while`.
Second you are doing this in awfully complicated way - it may be simpler to read whole lines in loop and then working with string to parse it.

Also you seem to adding digits as characters so result you are getting is probably average of their ASCII codes

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the single single character so using this one you can't get the real answer.

To get the total input from the file you can use

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

Then getting the input from the string you can use the sscanf.

```
int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

Then use six variables for getting the input including the id no. Then add the five variables and done the average for that.

```
 sscanf(s,"%d %d %d %d %d %d",&id,&m1,&m2,&m3,&m4,&m5);
```

then `avg=(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5)/5".`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#define MAXSCCORES 5

 FILE *fp = NULL;
fopen_s (&fp, "data.txt","r");

int student = 0;
int score[MAXSCORES];

while (!feof(fp))
{
    int count = fscanf_s(fp,"%d %d %d %d %d %d", &student, &score[0], &score[1], &score[2], &score[3], &score[4] );
    if ( count == MAXSCORES+1 )
    {
        for (int i=1; i<MAXSCORES; i++)
            score[0] += score[i];
        score[0] = score[0] / MAXSCORES;
        printf ("student %d Average Score = %d\n", student, score[0] );
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```